# Layout Weight in Linear Layout Android?

Tags: android

I am using two ListView in my Layout. and having fixed header and footer.But when i am running my code my header is getting breaked not coming full on my Device and my footer is not showing because of the ListView .

This is my main XML file that is having the ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llHeader"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/back_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:text="Flights"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/flightDetailsLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerflightDetailsLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Boston to San Fransisco, "
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripType"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:text="RoundTrip"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/innerTripLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="19 Jan 2013 " 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/paxText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="for 1 Adults,0 Childs,O Infants"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Book"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tripDate"
                android:layout_width="84dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:text="Rs 10,2345 "
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bookBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/book" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sortFlightLayouts"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightDetailsLayout"
        android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="DEL-BLR"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flight_icon_result" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rupee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_bg123"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="BLR-DEL"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/flight_icon_result" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/time" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/rupee" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvDepartures"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <ListView
             android:id="@+id/lvArrivals"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llFooter"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bg" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/filter" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sort" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this my Layout that i am putting in the ListView at RunTime

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flightLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:src="@drawable/spicejet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flightCompanyName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightLogo"
        android:text="Spice Jet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flightNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightCompanyName"
        android:text="9W-123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flightTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flightLogo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="6:00 - 7:00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flightStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightTime"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flightLogo"
        android:text="1h 35m | Non Stop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flightStop"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flightLogo"
        android:text="Rs 20,000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Remove everything from layout, Now start building layout again, adding one view at a time, and previewing how it looks like. When you have zeroed on the particular change/addition that causes trouble, post that relevant information/part here, with screen shots showing the difference.

Comment: I'm sorry but your code it's quite a mess, i can't understand what you are aiming for, can u please draw and example of how you imagine your layout? With an idea in mind will be more easy for us to help you. Anyway some fast tips: if you use `android:layout_weight="1"` in a view, the father of that view must have a `android:weightSum=""` parameter, otherwise `layout_weight` will have no effects. I also link u [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)  that could help you with the basic use of layouts view

Comment: @RobertoLombardini the parent doesn't always need a `weight_sum`. It should if not all children have a `weight` that sum to 1

Comment: @codeMagic nice, i don't know that. I know i'm a bit OT but could you please explain how works `android:layout_weight="1"` without weightSum? Thank you.

Comment: @RobertoLombardini Its a bit difficult to understand at first and I don't know how well I can explain it but i can try. If all children `Views` have `weights` that sum to 1 then the system decides what the `weight_sum` should be by adding them up. According to a discussion I had with RomainGuy and someone else on here, it is safer to leave out the `weight_sum` if the children sum to 1

Comment: @RobertoLombardini Found it, from Romain Guy, "weightSum can be useful if you want a View to occupy for instance 50% of the available space. Create a LinearLayout with a weightSum of 1.0, add a single child, give it a width of 0 and a weight of 0.5 and you'll get that effect. You could also have to children using only 25% of the available space left each, etc."

Comment: @codeMagic i'll give this a try, it will be more easy to understand it looking at some example. Thank you anyway ^^

Comment: @RobertoLombardini yes it will, that's why I wasn't sure how well I could explain without creating a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if this is your only problem yet but when you use `layout_weight` inside of a vertical `LinearLayout` then your `layout_height` should be `0dp`.

Likewise if it is inside of a horizontal `LinearLayout` then the `layout_width` should be `0dp`. Also, all of the `layouts` should have a `weight` if you are using it on one of thenm.

`android:layout_below=` in your third `LinearLayout`, I believe, is not a property of `LinearLayout`. That is a property of `RelativeLayout`.

My suggestion for this type of setup is to use `RelativeLayout` as the root `layout`. Then, for your header `LinearLayout` you can use `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and for your footer use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` then stick your `ListView` in the middle with `android:layout_below="@id/idOfHeaderLL"`

```
<RelativeLayout
  ...>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/headerLL"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      ...>
     <!-- add header veiws -->
    </LinearLayout
    <ListView
       android:layout_below="@id/headerLL"
       .../>
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       ...>
    <!-- add footer views -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not going to rewrite the whole layout but that should give you an idea. The "..." is where you will put in your other properties such as height, width, etc...

Comment: will u please put the XML that will be more helpfull to me

Comment: i have done the changes as per u but now it is throwing error at onewayListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvDepartures); LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ListView

Comment: Clean your project. In Eclipse, "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: You're welcome. You should refer to the [Layouot Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) to know which properties are available for each.